# Liquibse updateToTag

Tags: sql-server, database, liquibase

In my environment, there is a need to re-run several scripts as part of each DB change install. I use the "runAlways" tag for this and everything works fine (standard run "liquibse update" command), but when I started to use TAGs and run commands as "updateToTag" then the "runAlways" tag is ignored, example below.

File1 '1.0.0.xml' with changes

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <databaseChangeLog
      xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
             http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">
    
        <changeSet author="test1" id="script1" dbms="mssql" runInTransaction="false" runAlways="true">
            <comment>script1</comment>  
            <sqlFile
                    encoding="UTF-8"                
                    path="script1.sql"
                    relativeToChangelogFile="true"
                    splitStatements="false"
                    stripComments="true"/>
        </changeSet>
        <changeSet author="test" id="script2" dbms="mssql" runInTransaction="false" runAlways="true">
            <comment>script2</comment>  
            <sqlFile
                    encoding="UTF-8"                
                    path="script2.sql"
                    relativeToChangelogFile="true"
                    splitStatements="false"
                    stripComments="true"/>
        </changeSet>
    
    </databaseChangeLog>
```

Master file2:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <databaseChangeLog
          xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                 http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">
        
          <include file="1.0.0.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
          <changeSet id="1.0.0" author="test" runAlways="true">
            <tagDatabase tag="1.0.0"/>
          </changeSet>
         
          <include file="2.0.0.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
          <changeSet id="2.0.0" author="test" runAlways="true">
            <tagDatabase tag="2.0.0"/>
          </changeSet>
        
    </databaseChangeLog>
```

My run sequence:

```
Step1

liquibase updateToTag 2.0.0

--> Result: Scripts correctly installed on DB

Step2

liquibase updateToTag 2.0.0

--> Result: "AlwaysRun" scripts not re-ran on DB
```

Any ideas why the liquibase is ignoring the "runAlways" tag? Thanks

Liquibase Version: 4.6.1

similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68224830

Comment: Can you paste the entire commands you run at step 1 & 2? Thanks!